# Proactive Message, Received error 401 "Authorization has been denied for this request"

Tags: botframework

I'm trying to send a proactive message using botframework in Nodejs (Teams channel), but a received 401 error.

I make some searches and I found that the error can be possible with the trust service URL, but I have already done that part.

My adpter config

```
const {
    BotFrameworkAdapter,
} = require('botbuilder');

const { MicrosoftAppCredentials } = require('botframework-connector');

const adapter = new BotFrameworkAdapter({
    appId: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_ID,
    appPassword: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD
})
```

Send proactive message code

```
adapter.continueConversation(address, async (t) => {
            MicrosoftAppCredentials.trustServiceUrl(process.env.MICROSOFT_BOT_SERVICE_URL);
            await t.sendActivity(model.render());
        }).then((r) => {
            console.log("continue")
            console.log(r)
            res.status(200).send({
                status: "OK"
            })
        }).catch((e) => {
            console.log(e);
            res.send("ERRO " + e)
        });
```

Request and response, with my AppId and conversation ID.

```
statusCode: 401,
>    request: WebResource {
>      streamResponseBody: false,
>      url: 'https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/v3/conversations/a%3A1MUpsVB7CH-6BTiSUHxOkMhv05saxu9O7qe0zRNPR04PCvXp-6QzsoYKpT-oykqyJpu8SgbawTkbUDauiBGF9bIeG9qg56Ts6lpEGgY6SSrMMj5YL_K-yxOJ5jjoqIrJQ/activities',
>      method: 'POST',
>      headers: HttpHeaders { _headersMap: [Object] },
>      body: '{"type":"message","serviceUrl":"https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/","channelId":"msteams","from":{"id":"c96afa27-addb-4bc8-80fb-c0317380bf1a","name":"Luna"},"conversation":{"id":"a:1MUpsVB7CH-6BTiSUHxOkMhv05saxu9O7qe0zRNPR04PCvXp-6QzsoYKpT-oykqyJpu8SgbawTkbUDauiBGF9bIeG9qg56Ts6lpEGgY6SSrMMj5YL_K-yxOJ5jjoqIrJQ"},"text":"Achei aqui! A OV de número 0001302956","inputHint":"acceptingInput"}',
>      query: undefined,
>      formData: undefined,
>      withCredentials: false,
>      abortSignal: undefined,
>      timeout: 0,
>      onUploadProgress: undefined,
>      onDownloadProgress: undefined,
>      operationSpec: {
>        httpMethod: 'POST',
>        path: 'v3/conversations/{conversationId}/activities',
>        urlParameters: [Array],
>        requestBody: [Object],
>        responses: [Object],
>        serializer: [Serializer]
>      }
>    },
>    response: {
>      body: '{"message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}',
>      headers: HttpHeaders { _headersMap: [Object] },
>      status: 401
>    },
>    body: { message: 'Authorization has been denied for this request.' }
>  }
```

[configs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkMWn.png)

[send proactive message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGo1W.png)

[Request and response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfDIC.png)

Comment: As we got this closed in your GH issue, please "accept" and upvote it so others can quickly find the answer and I can clear this from my support tracker.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw this was [a duplicate of your GitHub issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/bot-docs/issues/1860). I'll post my answer here for others:

The issue is that in `sendMessage.f.js`, you're [instantiating a new `BotFrameworkAdapter`](https://github.com/vinisbranco/hyper-automation/blob/master/functions/message/sendMessage.f.js#L17), which differs from the one instantiated [in `gateway.f.js`](https://github.com/vinisbranco/hyper-automation/blob/master/functions/chatBot/gateway.f.js#L7), which you use to create the conversationReference.

They *look* the same because you're passing in the same appId/password, but [their `BotIdentityKey` differs](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/master/libraries/botbuilder-core/src/botAdapter.ts#L32) because the key is generated using `Symbol()`, which as you may know, [guarantees a unique key gets generated every time it's called, even with the same input.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol#Description) This BotIdentityKey is used in some auth chaching, deep in the code.

If you want to keep them in separate files, I'd recommend exporting your adapter in `gateway.f.js` and importing it in `sendMessage.f.js`.

*Note: I confirmed this was the issue by running Sample 57, verifying it worked, then instantiating a new adapter in the proactive message section. I, too, got the 401 error.*